# Setting up default mapping Elasticsearch

Tags: json, indexing, lucene, elasticsearch, mapping

From the documentation you can set up default mapping definition for every index just putting the .json file inside $ELASTICSEARCH_HOME/config/mappings/_default

However, after doing this, I just get the error:

MapperParsingException[mapping [default_mapping]]; nested: MapperParsingException[Root type mapping not empty after parsing!

My mapping file looks like:

```
 {
  "event" : {
    "dynamic_templates" : [
      {
        "template_1" : {
          "match" : "*",
          "mapping" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The problem is that I need to setup several things for each index I create, but I don't want to care about updating the map per index, since I would need to ask if the index exists before doing this. That means, during my workflow I just want to index documents, do not want to care about settings stuff.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this specific issue using index templates. However, I still feel like there's something missing here...

I would appreciate any further information about this topic.

Thanks!